# In Python, if I have a 2D List, How do I transfer the elements of one 2D List into another 2D List but in different order?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

[the actual code of printing in columns A B C](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOyt6.png)

In Python, 
I am able to print this

```
abcd  efgh  ijkl    
mno   pqr   stuv
```

what if I want to print it like this?

```
abcd ijkl  efgh
mno  stuv  pqr
```

Comment: Please show how you are "_able to print this_".

Comment: It's better to post your code in your question (formatted as code), rather than an image file. Plus, your code is doing a lot more, it's not clear how it directly relates to the question you posted. Please show how the python 2D array is defined, how you are printing it, and the order you want it printed out in instead (are you just wanting to swap the 2nd and 3rd columns, or are you looking for something more general?

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the output you desire assuming that you are starting with a list of lists of strings.

```
string_lists = [["abcd", "efgh", "ijkl"], ["mno", "pqr", "stuv"]]

for item in string_lists:
    # get the first item
    # use slicing to get items 1 to end, reverse with [::-1]
    # use spread operator to spread inside of a new list
    print([item[0], *item[1:][::-1]])
```

OUTPUT:

```
['abcd', 'ijkl', 'efgh']
['mno', 'stuv', 'pqr']
```

Resource: [Indexing and Slicing in Python](https://realpython.com/lessons/indexing-and-slicing/)

If you want to print the tabular data just as it is in the question you can do it with this code.

```
import textwrap

# Calculate the length of the longest string
COLSIZE = max(len(item) for items in string_lists for item in items)

# List of reordered lists
data = [[item[0], *item[1:][::-1]] for item in string_lists]

# Use str.ljust and textwrap wrap with joins to print tabular data
print(
    "\n".join(
        map(
            " ".join,
            (
                [s.ljust(COLSIZE) for s in textwrap.wrap(" ".join(col), COLSIZE)]
                for col in data
            ),
        )
    )
)
```

OUTPUT:

```
abcd ijkl efgh
mno  stuv pqr
```

Resource: [textwrap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html)